# How to install python 3.4 on pidora

Tags: python, software-installation

I recently changed to pidora as my pi operating system. Then I lost the WiFi adapter and my router is downstairs. I downloaded and extracted the python download from python.org but the instructions only say:

```
./configure
Make test
sudo install test
```

Can anyone help me to install python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command-line package manager on pidora is `yum`, the equivalent of `apt` on raspbian.<sup>1</sup>  You can search for packages with `yum search`, but `yum search python` is going to return umpteen hundred python related things, so:

```
yum search python | grep "^python"
```

Will filter for packages whose name starts with `python`.  That's a bit of an excessive list too, but the relevant package is presumably `python3`.  For more details:

```
> yum info python3
Available Packages
Name        : python3
Arch        : armv6hl
Version     : 3.3.2
```

So the latest pidora package is 3.3.2.  If you really want 3.4, you can [download the source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) (might as well use the latest 3.5 in that case) and there should be build instructions in the `tar`chive; first you have to unpack it:

- For the gzipped package:

  ```
  tar -xzf whatever.tgz
  ```
- Or, for the XZ package:

  ```
  tar -xJf whatever.tar.xz
  ```

You'll need `tar` and the relevant compression tool installed (`yum install gzip` / `xz`). It is basically:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I would just `su root` to do that rather than using `sudo`.

**However,** I strongly encourage you stick with the distro's 3.3 if at all feasible.  Building python on the pi is, I would guess, going to be tedious and potential frustrating with all the prereqs, not to mention it will take a while.  And not guaranteed to succeed.

Note it is not unusual to have both a 2.x and 3.x installed.  Pidora requires 2.x, so that will already be there.

---

<sup>1. Yum might seem slower than apt sometimes because it caches less, but (in my experience) it also tends to be more reliable.</sup>

Comment: I don't have any version of python installed on pidora, I'll try what you said and i will report back.

Comment: Really?  So `python` at the command line says "command not found"?  I was under the impression Fedora used python scripts in its base system (e.g., I think yum uses it for some stuff), but I could be wrong.  BTW, in case it's not clear, to install 3.3 just `yum install python3`.

Comment: I try `yum info python3` but that returns not found. Remember I said I don't have access to the internet. (Lost the wifi adapter and router is downstairs)

Comment: Can you not use an Ethernet cable... or by saying it is "downstairs" you mean you are not able to physically access the router?

Comment: I can't physically access the router. PS how do I do the `./configure > make > make install` thing? Im getting ./configure - no such directory. (Im on the usb directory)

Comment: I can almost promise you are going to wish you did make an effort to access the internet and use the distro package.   I've never compiled python, but it could take hours on the pi.  Like, even *4-6+* hours.  And if it screws up, you may have to start from scratch again and hope you get it right...this time.  Anyway, I thought the question was about pidora, but if it is about compiling python, it is off-topic here.  There must be fairly decent documentation in that directory -- look for a `README`.   If that's not enough, try [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Also with regard to internet access: You almost certainly will not be able to compile python from source without it anyway.  It will have dependencies that are not installed on the system, and without internet access it is going to become a farce trying to get one after the other on a USB stick from where-ever you do have net access -- and then trying to build them, and working out their dependencies, and on and on.  **This is not a simple task.**  $0.02: Let it go for now until you can get another wifi adapter or something.